# How can I deploy Laravel and Wordpress together on Laravel Forge?

Tags: laravel, wordpress, laravel-forge

We are trying hard to deploy Laravel website with Wordpress on Laravel Forge but are unable to do so.

Say, if our domain is [example.com](https://example.com), the blog should be [example.com/blog](https://blog.example.com). However, what we currently have is [blog.example.com](https://blog.example.com), which is not serving the purpose.

It'd be great if someone can help us find a fix for deploying Laravel project with Wordpress on Laravel Forge without changing the URL structure.